# awk remove sign "," in all columns, if it exists between

Tags: linux, awk, editing

My data input file:

```
508,186,,Name,"VIA PAS, 4",vou1@mail.com,
291,345,,Name2,Votros 73,vou2@mail.com,
911,733,,Name3,zap 101,vou4@mail.com,
9000,32,,Michel,hops 12,"x1@mail.com, vou7@mail.com, vou12@mail.com",
```

My data output file:

```
508,186,,Name,**VIA PAS 4**,vou1@mail.com,
291,345,,Name2,Votros 73,vou2@mail.com,
911,733,,Name3,zap 101,vou4@mail.com,
9000,32,,Michel,hops 12, **x1@mail.com vou7@mail.com vou12@mail.com**,
```

So awk should find all places where is `""` and remove comma from `""`. And after remove `"` symbols. Would be easy if needed only remove "", but I need remove comas before. Notice, that commas are used as seperators as well.

Comment: This question was asked and answered on [unix.stackexcange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48672/17666).

Comment: awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "", $i) } 1' 1.csv > 2.csv worked like charm.